# Loopback - REST upsert / update based on other properties than id

Tags: javascript, rest, loopbackjs

For example I have loopback model which looks like that:

```
╔═══════╦════════╗
║ id    ║ Number ║
║ name  ║ String ║
║ prop1 ║ Number ║
║ prop2 ║ Number ║
╚═══════╩════════╝
```

*Combination of **Prop 1** and **Prop 2** must be unique.*

Then I have a record which looks like that:

```
╔═══════╦═════╗
║ id    ║ 22  ║
║ name  ║ Foo ║
║ prop1 ║ 2   ║
║ prop2 ║ 4   ║
╚═══════╩═════╝
```

I would like not to upsert by ID, but by combination of **prop 1** and **prop 2**. So for example when I send entity

```
{
    "name": "Bar",
    "prop1": 2,
    "prop2": 4
}
```

it should find record with combination of **prop1** and **prop2** and change name to **Bar**. If no record with this combination exists yet, it should create new one.

There is a REST method (method: PUT, path: '/'), which only do upsert by ID (as far as I know).

Comment: hey that table is interesting.. How do you do that? Some kind of automative tool?

Comment: Look at the `PATCH` verb, which I think corresponds to this behavior.

Comment: Amit Joki: It's some kind of handwork, based on http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post.

Comment: Dai: Can you please give me link to documentation? I could not find it.

Comment: Dai: Unfortunately, I think that `PATCH` verb is not supported.

Comment: my answer is correct, see below....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way to do this with Loopback is described in this document:

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API#PersistedModelRESTAPI-Updatemodelinstanceattributes

You have to do a POST request, not a PUT, to accomplish this with out-of-the-box Loopback behavior, as so:

```
POST /dogs/update?where[color]=blue  '{"color":"orange"}'
```

Answer (score -1):

Just call

```
/?filter[where][prop1]=2&filter[where][prop2]=4
```

with `PUT` method and

```
{
    "name": "Bar"
}
```

body.

source: http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/PersistedModel+REST+API